# Podman: changing mounted volume permissions

Tags: jupyterhub, podman

I have a folder, which originally has 0740 permissions.

I can not change the permissions of original folder for security reasons, neither can I use
`podman unshare chown` as I need to keep original ownership for using it outside the container.

What I want is to change the permissions of mounted volume to 0774 recursively (only read access required), keeping the original folder's permission unchanged.

Is it possible, and at which stage it should be done? I've tried to do this in pre_spawn_hook, but at this point there're no mounted volumes yet.